# Android: Can I have generic return type in AsyncTask - doInBackGround

Tags: android, generics, android-asynctask

My AsyncTask call web service & get the results in POJO. Now that POJOs are of different type. & AsyncTask is only one. So can I have Generic return type like

```
protected T <T> doInBackground(Class<T> ... classTypes) {
 //Code to call webservice & get pojo
 return calssType.cast(pojoObject)
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried...like `public class GeneralSearchTask<T> extends AsyncTask<Class<T> , Integer, <T> T> {....}` . But it is not possible I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tried setting return type to `Object`, then you should be able to cast it to any type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create One base class like POJOClass and it can be extended by required classes, Do type casting in async class.

```
yourTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, POJOClassObject> {

private ModelObject doInBackground(Object... params){... return POJOClassObject}

protected void onPostExecute(POJOClassObject object) {

//type cast here
}
```